# How can I start a http server in python which will support all methods ? Not a simpleHttpServer

Tags: python, python-3.x, httpserver

I am new to `Python` . I am creating a server using python . I have used a command

```
python -m http.server 8001
```

This is working fine . But I have some post , delete , put requests . SO , How can i achieve that ?

Comment: You have not provided any information about your code, such as which libraries you are using. Is it this? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/http

Comment: Yes I am using vesrsion 3.3.0

Comment: Of Python? Or the `http` library? I only see version 0.2 on pypi... I suggest that you look into learning a more serious web framework (such as Flask or Pyramid) if you want to do anything even relatively complex with HTTP in Python. It will be worth your time.